# How to compute number of elements in Gn

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$G_{n}$ is the set of invertible congruence classes of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. So, $[a]_{n}$ is in $G_{n}$ if and only if $a$ is relatively prime to $n$.

How do I compute the number of elements in $G_{n}$ if I'm given a value for $n$, i.e. $n=24,696$?

Comment: Let $\varphi(n)$ denote the number of positive integers relatively prime to $n$ ($\varphi$ is known as Euler's totient function). If $n = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}} \cdots p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}$ for distinct primes $p_{1}, \ldots, p_{k}$, then $\varphi(n) = \varphi(p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}) \cdots \varphi(p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}})$ (one way to prove this fact is using the Chinese Remainder Theorem). It's not hard to show that $\varphi(p^{k}) = p^{k} - p^{k-1}$ for $p$ prime, so putting these facts together, one can compute $\varphi(n)$ easily by computing the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim So the prime factorization of $24,696$ is $2^3 * 3^2 * 7^3$. Where do I proceed from here?

Comment: $\psi(\;(2^3)(3^2)(7^3)\;)=$ $\psi (2^3)\psi (3^2)\psi(7^3)=$ $(2^{3-1}(2-1))\cdot (3^{2-1}(3-1))\cdot (7^{3-1}(7-1)).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=p_{1}^{k_{1}}\cdot p_{2}^{k_{2}}\cdot...\cdot  p_{m}^{k_{m}}$, then $\varphi (n)=\left ( p_{1}^{k_{1}}-p_{1}^{k_{1}-1} \right )\cdot \left ( p_{2}^{k_{2}}-p_{2}^{k_{2}-1} \right )\cdot...\cdot  \left ( p_{m}^{k_{m}}-p_{m}^{k_{m}-1} \right ) $.
So, for $n=24696=2^3\cdot3^2\cdot7^3$, you'll get

$\varphi (24696)=\left ( 2^3-2^2 \right )\cdot \left ( 3^2-3 \right )\cdot \left ( 7^3-7^2 \right )=4\cdot6\cdot294=7056. $